Why does querying Strapi with "DRAFT" status return both published and drafted items in GraphQL?
I'm using Strapi as a headless CMS with the Draft & Publish feature enabled, and I'm querying the data using GraphQL in my project. The problem I'm facing is with filtering drafted and published content.
My setup:
I'm using the following GraphQL query to fetch wines:
query($filters: WineFiltersInput, $status: PublicationStatus) {
  wines(filters: $filters, status: $status) {
    title
    vintage
    documentId
    lot_number
    user {
      username
    }
    publishedAt
  }
}

The variables I'm passing for the draft status:
{
  "filters": {
    "user": {
      "username": {
        "eq": "wineCompany"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": "DRAFT"
}

The issue:

When I use status: "DRAFT", it returns both drafted and published products. However, the publishedAt field is null for all of them.

When I use status: "PUBLISHED", it correctly returns only the published products (with publishedAt containing a valid timestamp).


I expected the "DRAFT" status to return only the drafted products (those with publishedAt: null), but it's returning published products as well, even though their publishedAt value is missing.
My questions:

Why does querying with "DRAFT" status return both drafted and published products with publishedAt as null?

Is there something I’m missing in how Strapi handles PublicationStatus in GraphQL queries?

How can I filter drafts properly using the GraphQL API?

How to fetch all products (including drafts) using GraphQL in Strapi?


Any advice on how to resolve this would be appreciated!

any success with querying only elements with status Draft?
